# String contains method return false even when string contains substring

Tags: java, string, substring, equals, indexof

I have a string:

> 20160719_P_BID_20160718_130000

I need to check if this string contains the substring "BID". I have tried various methods like:

1. `.contains("BID") / .contains("_BID_")`
2. `.indexOf("BID")`
3. `.substring(11,14).equals("BID)`

but all methods have returned `false` even though the output of the strings does contain the string `"BID"` and is the string `"BID"`

Update:

```
String fileName = file.getFileName();
String tradeTypeStr = fileName.substring(11,14);        
if(tradeTypeStr.equalsIgnoreCase(tradeType))
```

Can someone shed some light as to why the methods are returning false?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show some more of your code please. I just ran `"20160719_P_BID_20160718_130000".contains("BID")` and the result is "true"

Comment: Have you tried copying the exact String and pasting into the code?

Comment: .contains method should works. Would you post the exact code you tested with?

Comment: debug and check the value coming in variable `fileName`

Comment: You must print tradeTypeStr  to see what is the value that you are comparing.

Comment: @Vishal: have debugged and checked the value, it contains "BID"

Comment: @Gaurava: i have printed it, the substring is "BID"

Comment: System.out.println("20160719_P_BID_20160718_130000".substring(11,14).equalsIgnoreCase("BID")); return true

Comment: `.contains` work for any string other than BID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since String.contains() and String.indexOf() definitely works, this sounds like you may have a problem with your encoding. Try

```
    String fileName = file.getName();
    for (char c : fileName.toCharArray())
    {
        System.out.println(c + " : " + Integer.toHexString(c));
    }
```

If you don't find something like

```
_ : 5f
B : 42
I : 49
D : 44
_ : 5f
```

you've got the reason for your problem

Comment: Thank you! you've been most helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Test this

```
String fileName = file.getName();

if(fileName.contains(tradeTypeStr))
```

Comment: Maybe you are changing your keyboard language when typing "BID"! Could you use copy and paste from debugging variable of fileName? It should work.